# Android WebView with notifications bar

Tags: android, webview, notification-bar

I would like to make my webapp look as similar as I can to a native app, now I just realized that there's no notification bar at the top and that Android back button doesn't take you to the last screen but closes the app. Does anybody know how to fix this?

*Manifest*

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mywebapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

*Activity*

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final String URL = "file:///android_asset/Compatibilidades/public_html/index.html";
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    myWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    myWebView.loadUrl(URL);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}

class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    return false;
}
}
```

*Layout*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, you need to put this parameter in the activity in *AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<activity
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to support the back button, you can do the following ([source](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/gettingstarted)):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```